# How do I copy a file that contains the same string as the directory?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I currently have these directories:

```
C:\testfolder\100
C:\testfolder\101
C:\testfolder\102
```

and I have these files in the same directory:

```
C:\testfolder\file-100.txt
C:\testfolder\file-101.txt
C:\testfolder\file-102.txt
```

What I was trying to do in VB is move text file `file-100.txt` to the `100` directory. Same for text file `file-101.txt`, move it to its pertaining folder `101`.

My question is how can I write a loop so that my program matches part of the string of my text file name and move it to the matching folder name? Moving one file at a time wouldn't be effecient since I have hundreds of directories and files to apply this to.

Edit:

I'm somewhat familiar with VB. I was having trouble with the logical part of this, in which I couldn't think of a way to write a loop so that it can transfer the files for me.

Comment: Which part of this task are you having trouble with?  Getting the destination folder path for a given file path?  Moving the file?  Constructing the loop?  Getting the list of files to move?  Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: So you just need to figure out how to get the destination folder path from a given file path?  If so, are the file names always formatted in that same way?

Comment: That `SearchAllSubDirectories` option doesn't make sense since you are moving files from a parent directory to a child directory.  That option will find those files you moved and try to move them again.

Comment: Ok. I'll remove it for I don't want it to cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Without error checking, this would be a simple routine to move those files.  It's based on your file names being consistent:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim homePath As String = "c:\testfolder"

  Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(homePath, "*.txt")
  For Each f As String In files
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(f)

    Dim destPath As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
    destPath = destPath.Split("-")(1)
    destPath = Path.Combine(homePath, destPath)

    Dim destFile As String = Path.Combine(destPath, fileName)

    File.Move(f, destFile)
  Next
End Sub
```

This just gets the list of text files in your directory, parses the file name to get just the number value (100, 101, etc), and then reconstructs the new path.  It assumes the directories exist, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to find matched pattern

```
    Dim dir As String = "C:\testfolder\"
    Dim fileList() As String = {"C:\testfolder\file-100.txt", _
                                "C:\testfolder\file-101.txt", _
                                "C:\testfolder\file-102.txt"}

    Dim pattern As New Regex(Replace(dir, "\", "\\") & "file-([0-9]+)[.]txt")

    For Each value As String In fileList
        Dim match As Match = pattern.Match(value)
        If match.Success Then
            MsgBox("move from " & dir & " to " & dir & match.Groups(1).Value)
        End If
    Next
```

Make sure you have import RegularExpressions.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub organizeFiles(ByVal folderPath As String)
    For Each filePath As String In Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt")
        Dim destinationFilePath As String = getDestinationFilePath(filePath)
        If destinationFilePath IsNot Nothing Then
            File.Move(filePath, destinationFilePath)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Function getDestinationFilePath(ByVal filePath As String) As String
    Const fileNamePrefix As String = "file-"
    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
    Dim fileNameWithoutExtension As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)
    If Not fileNameWithoutExtension.StartsWith(fileNamePrefix) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If
    Dim folderName As String = fileNameWithoutExtension.Substring(fileNamePrefix.Length)
    Dim fileFolderPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
    Dim destinationFolderPath As String = Path.Combine(fileFolderPath, folderName)
    Dim destinationFilePath As String = Path.Combine(destinationFolderPath, fileName)
    Return destinationFilePath
End Function
```